# pymongo error name 'ISODate' is not defined

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

query:

```
    query = mycol.aggregate([
        {
            "$addFields": {
                "Date": {
                    "$dateFromString": {
                        "dateString": "$date",
                        "format": "%d/%m/%Y"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$match": {
                "Date": { "$gte": ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00Z"), "$lt": ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
            }
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                    "_id" : "$Employee", "total": { "$push" : "$salary" }
                }
        }
    ])
```

error:

```
    NameError at /api/category/top-needstates/
    name 'ISODate' is not defined
```

Here i am using mongodb with python using pymongo.
But i am getting above error.

Is there any way to fix it?

Do i need to import ISODate?

PLease have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use native Python types and Pymongo will automatically translate them into BSON - ISODate in this case ([docs](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html#documents)):

```
{
     "$match": {
            "Date": { "$gte": datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0), "$lt": datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0) }
     }
 }
```

Example [here](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html#range-queries)